# Install a Ruby located on local system using RVM

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm

How would one install a Ruby VM (JRuby, Ruby MRI, etc.) on a machine that doesn't have internet access?

I'd like to just drop the tar.gz file somewhere that RVM is able to see (or checks before it goes out and tries to retrieve the package itself). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

[This blog post](http://minhajuddin.com/2010/07/22/install-a-ruby-version-with-rvm-when-offline/) explains that you can drop the source archive in your `$HOME/.rvm/archives` directory.

> ```
> cp ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02.tar.gz /home/minhajuddin/.rvm/archives
> rvm install ree-1.8.7
> ```

Or [the docs](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/cli/) say that you can specify the archives directory from the command line:

> `--archives   - directory for downladed files (~/.rvm/archives/)`

Comment: When I tried the first method, rvm went merrily out to the web to try to download the requested Ruby...

When I tried the second method:
rvm install ruby-1.9.2 --archives "~/.rvm/archives/"
Unrecognized command line argument: '~/.rvm/archives/' ( see: 'rvm usage' )